# clicking sounds after install ubuntu 22.04 laptop msi gl73 8se

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

I hear strange sounds like clicks while using the system. I think it's the sound card. My laptop includes the problematic sound chip Realtek ALC1220. I have read many solutions but none have worked for me. Actually I am using windows, but I would be interested in using ubuntu on my computer. I don't know if a compatible usb sound card will work well for me. The sound works fine on windows but I want to use ubuntu instead of windows

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu or not? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I had ubuntu installed but the sound was not working properly.

Comment: Right now I'm using ubuntu with the sound card turned off by bios and it doesn't make those noises.